# Process don't response to signals

Tags: linux

Using CLI I try to close/send to background a process which loads at startup - the first thing I see is that process and not the regular shell.

Ctrl x/c/z  don't work.  Kill -9 does (connecting with ssh and send the signal)

If I kill the process (which loads at startup) and then execute it again , it will reapond to each signal.

I try to figure out what could be the problem

I can't post the program's source (related to workplace). Lets say it's a simple printf("hello world\n") , scanf and return. since this program autostart during kernel startup (with inittab script..) is it possible that it starts before the bash shell and thats why it can't recieve these signals?

Comment: What have you tried? Include a code snippet please.

Comment: what do you mean by what I tried?   you need the process code itself?

Comment: Yes, show the code you have written which does not work.

Comment: I can't do that (related to workplace). Lets say it's a simple printf("hello world\n") and then scanf..          since this program autostart during kernel startup (with inittab script..) is it possible that it starts before the bash shell and thats why it can't recieve these signals?

Comment: Ok, then update your question with that info as well.